# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager only in Production mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This error: 'Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTView" was not found in the UIManager' is coming up only when I disable __DEV__.
I tried:

- running react-native link in the root directory
- downgrading to react-native 55.0.0
- cleared cache
- removed node_modules and reinstalled them
- cleaned project in android studio

When I run with __DEV__ everything works fine.
The error only appears in production mode.

I have tried everything suggested in similar posts with no results.
Any suggestions ?